# Linux kernel version numbering

Tags: linux-kernel

A while ago, I downloaded Linux kernel source 2.6.38.8 from kernel.org (http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.38.8.tar.gz). Today, I cloned github.com/torvalds/linux and tried to find the commit that produced that exact version. The closed thing I could find was a tag for v2.6.38-rc8.

When I did a `diff -r` on the two directories, there were 775 files that diffed (not including any files under `.git/`). Can anyone explain (or link an article) how the releases on http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6 are created vs. the git tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linus does not produce/tag sub-releases, only the major releases.

You want the linux-stable tree to find the .8 release. git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

Note that Linus *did* tag v2.6.38 so you either didn't pull recently enough or didn't sort the tags correctly or something.